# Android Studio - NameValuePair and HttpParams is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android development and I am have some deprecated issues. In Android Studio, it is stating that the `NameValuePair` and `HttpParams` is deprecated.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", user.fname));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", user.lname));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password)); 

HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "register");
```

When searching for answers, I am getting sent to use `openconnection()`, but I don't see how that applies to code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use ContentValues ?

From this snippet of code I am not sure if it would help you.

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

  values.put("fname",user.fname);
  values.put("lname", user.lname);
  values.put("email",user.email);
  values.put("password",user.password);
```

Comment: That would help resolve the NamValuePair.  What about the HttpParams?

Comment: I would swear that you editted it, did not see HttpParams. I think there are libraries that would surely help you with that you want to do. For me, for everything I needed was RetroFit.

Comment: What do you need exactly ?

Comment: I need to pass form parameters to an api on a web server.  Then also retrieve the result of the api to show in the Android application.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the dependencies of HttpClient in your build.gradle file:

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use contentvalues or hashmap based on your preference.

i have used Content values

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("key1","value1");
contentValues.put("key2","value2");
```

and if the data that u are posting is form data then here`s how u can convert it form data

```
 public String getFormData(ContentValues contentValues) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : contentValues.valueSet()) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            sb.append("&");

        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        sb.append("=");
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue().toString(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below dependencies for both `NameValuePair` & `Httpclient` to make this work.

```
dependencies{
      compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just adding the dependencies in gradle:

```
dependencies{
  implementation'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```